# What is the key binding to enter input string in C-s or C-r in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

In finding string in the current buffer, I know that we can use C-s or C-r, then you'll have the minibuffer prompt of what the string to be search. I know that we can use M-p or M-n to go to that prompt, but unfortunately emacs will display the previous search query.

I don't like using backspace to delete it, is there any key in which the prompt can be cleared from previous searches? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you saying you want to change your search term while you are already in the process of searching?

A couple of simple options are:

1. Break out of the search first. I usually just do something which moves point, such as <kbd>C-a</kbd>. Then when you <kbd>C-s</kbd> again, the prompt will be blank (unless you type it twice, in which case it will search for the previous pattern again).

   <kbd>RET</kbd> is `isearch-exit`, but that has a different effect with no pattern, and I prefer the consistency. You could also use <kbd>C-g</kbd> (`isearch-abort`), but you may need to type that repeatedly, depending on what happened up to that point.

   <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> runs `isearch-cancel` which will reliably "Terminate the search and go back to the starting point", which may sometimes be preferable to <kbd>C-a</kbd> which will leave you on the line where you typed it.
2. You can edit the pattern on the fly with <kbd>M-e</kbd>, and then delete the whole thing with normal editing commands. After editing, type <kbd>RET</kbd> to continue searching for your newly-edited pattern.

Type <kbd>C-s</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd> for the built-in help.

Comment: Thanks @phils. The `M-e` almost what I want, is there any similiar keystroke that automatically clear the input ? I've try the `M-e`, but I must press delete key...

Comment: You can use any editing commands, so `M-e` `C-a` `C-k` would kill the existing search term

Answer (score 1):

Try binding a key to the M-x search-forward command.

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'search-forward)`

This will automatically focus on the minibuffer and clear previous input.

Comment: Ah, this is almost what I want. But, if I do search again, which normally using `C-s`, now clear the minibuffer and prompt it again. Any idea of subsequent `C-s` will do next search?